# Single function for multiple v-model in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to get the more than one v-model value to one common function.
In my case, input validation for the multiple fields using common function inside the method in vue script.

```
<input type="number" v-model="field1" @keypress="onlyTwoDecimal" >
<input type="number" v-model="field2"@keypress="onlyTwoDecimal" ><input type="number" v-model="field2" @keypress="onlyTwoDecimal" 

<script>......    ....    method:{onlyTwoDecimal ($event) {  let keyCode = ($event.keyCode ? $event.keyCode : $event.which);

    // only allow number and one dot
    if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && (keyCode !== 46 || this.field1.indexOf('.') != -1)) { // 46 is dot
     $event.preventDefault();
    }

    // restrict to 2 decimal places
    if(this.field1!=null && this.field1.indexOf(".")>-1 && (this.field1.split('.')[1].length > 1)){
    $event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of `fields` and use `v-for`.

```
<div v-for="(field,index) in fields" :key="index">
  <input type="number" v-model="field" @keypress="onlyTwoDecimal">
</div>
```